# How do I open a document in XPages mobile controls from a URL?

Tags: xpages

I have the same issue as listed below.

How do I open a document in XPages mobile controls from a URL?

My application notifies users about pending review using an embedded URL link in an email. The requirement is to open the document in mobile controls (SinglePage/App Page). As of now I get a grey page on ipad when the link is clicked from the email.

Comment: I dont have these settings in the application properties, I am using Extlib853. I already added mobile prefix and the mobile page starts with the prfix.

Comment: Can you post a copy of the link, and then the mobile code.

Comment: This is the url in the document link of the email.

http://10.10.0.0/user/IT/ITHelp.nsf/m_Home.xsp&documentId=441A3649ECD7EFA043257C98006A7438&action=editDocument

Comment: I'll assume that the m_home is a page that displays a document?

Comment: yes m_home is the page that displays a document. This is the url in the link provided in the email. http://10.10.0.0/user/IT/ITHelp.nsf/m_Home.xsp&documentId=441A3649ECD7EFA043257C98006A7438&action=editDocument

Answer (score 1):

[image]If you have built a mobile page you want to use a mobile prefix.

Go into application configuration>XSP properties
Change the option to use the mobile theme for pages that start "m_" and make sure your mobile page starts with the prefix.